# Select a specific node which has a child node with specific value

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Row>
    <Cell>some value</Cell>
    <Cell>some value</Cell>
    ... continues with around 800 other Cells
  </Row>
  ...continues with around 2000 other Rows
```

**FIRST PROBLEM:**
By using xpath to select xml data, I want to select a Row which has a cell with a specific value. how can I achieve this ? What is the xpath syntax for this ?

**SECOND PROBLEM:**
My xml data is around 1.6m lines of code and selecting data from it takes a very long time, aside from the fact that it weights around 80Mbs! How can i make this process more effective and improve the performance ?
p.n I use the code below to retrieve xml data:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", dname ,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp;
}

var x=loadXMLDoc("data/data.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="some path";
if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
    var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result=nodes.iterateNext();

    while (result)
    {
        document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br>");
        result=nodes.iterateNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: the xpath `//Cell[.='some value']` should retrieve the nodes with cells having text content as `some value`

Comment: @svasa but this only selects the Cell with the value. I want to select its parent ! is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Yes. `//Cell[.='some value']/..` will give the parent node `Row`

Comment: @svasa Unfortunately , it does not work. I select `//Cell[.='some value']` it works fine, but when I add the `/..` it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the first part of your question:

```
//row[./cell/text() = '3']
```

Applying this XPath expression to the following XML

```
<root>
  <row>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>2</cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>3</cell>
    <cell>4</cell>
  </row>
</root>
```

produces the following output:

```
> xmllint -xpath "//row[./cell/text() = '3']" test.xml 
<row>
  <cell>3</cell>
  <cell>4</cell>
</row>
```

As for the second part of your question, the problem is that building the complete DOM for such a large document is quite expensive. So you need to look into event driven parsing (SAX, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML), but I have no personal experience with that.

Comment: Thanks ! by the way do you think XPath is the best way I can retrieve XML data from javascript ?

Comment: @MehdiJorJor Sorry, I have not much experience with Javascript.